# Dimension of subspace annihilated by set of linear functional.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, functional-calculus

> Let F be subfield of complex number We define n linear functional as $f_k(x_1,....x_n)=\sum^n_{i=1}(k-i)x_i$
>   I wanted to find dimension of subspace annihilated by $f_1,...f_k$
>   
>   My attempt I had use 2 method which gives me 2 different answer. I convinced with both but I do not know which is right or wrong.

1 Way:

Rank of matrix formed by the above functional is $2$.
Implies Null space union of all functionals is $n-2$ dimensional

2 ways:

$f_1(1,0,0,0...,0)=f_1(e_1)=0 $ by putting in the above formula
Similary $f_k(e_k)=0$ for every $k=1,...,n$.
Also $f_k(e_j)\neq 0 ,j\neq k$ so $e_1$ is annihilated by $f_1$ but by no other functional. So if we take intersection of subspace annihilated by all then it will be $0$. 
This implies only $0$ is  annihilated by all functionals. 
So dimension of subspace annihilated by that functionals is 0.
Where does my mistake occur?
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: In the second way, you have the subspaces $\ker(f_1), \ldots, \ker(f_k)$. You observed that $e_i\notin \ker(f_j)$ when $i\neq j$, and this is correct. But then you say that since $\cap_{i=1}^n \ker(f_i)$ does not contain any of the basis vectors $e_1, \ldots, e_n$, it must be $\{0\}$. 

It is not true that a subspace which does not contain any of the basis vectors must be the $0$ vector space. In fact, in an $n$-dimensional space with a fixed basis, you can come up with an $d$-dimensional subspace which contains none of the basis vectors for any $0\leqslant d\leqslant n-1$.

Comment: Thanks Sir but with same argument can we it has n-2 dimension?

Comment: I think it would be difficult to say what the dimension of a subspace is by making a finite list of points which are not in it. For any finite list (or any countable list of points) in an $n$-dimensional space and any $0\leqslant d<n$, I can find a $d$-dimensional subspace which doesn't contain any of the points on the list. 

If you have to have a second way to check that the dimension of the annihilator is $n-2$, I would recommend trying to find a basis for the annihilator consisting of $n-2$ vectors.